# building a python database query that supports multiple values for a single query parameter or none at all

Tags: python, postgresql, api

I am building a function to query my database and retrieve some records. The query string I receive can have up to four parameters, none of which are required, and some of which can have multiple values attached.

For example:

```
https://{api}?location="loc1,loc2,loc3"&source="name1"
```

In this example the `location` query string parameter has three values.  The `source` parameter has one value. And the other six query string parameters are not included.

The function I currently have works like this: initially a variable representing each query string parameter is set to `None`.  Then each potential query string parameter is checked and if it exists the variable is updated. My SQL query is then constructed to get data which matches the variable strings and if the variable hasn't been updated (still `None`) than ignore this search parameter.

```
    earlydate = None
    laterdate = None
    source = None
    filter = None
    ticker = None
    mentions = None
    upvotes = None
    subgroup = None
    location = None
    if event['queryStringParameters'].get('earlyDate'):
        earlydate = json.dumps(event['queryStringParameters']['earlyDate'])
    if event['queryStringParameters'].get('laterDate'):    
        laterdate = json.dumps(event['queryStringParameters']['laterDate'])
    if event['queryStringParameters'].get('source'):    
        source = event['queryStringParameters'].get('source')
    if event['queryStringParameters'].get('location'):
        location = event['queryStringParameters'].get('location')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgres_get_query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (location = %(location)s OR %(location)s IS NULL) and (time > %(earlydate)s OR %(earlydate)s IS NULL) and (time < %(laterdate)s OR %(laterdate)s IS NULL) and (source = %(source)s OR %(source)s IS NULL)"
    cursor.execute(postgres_get_query, {'earlydate': earlydate, 'laterdate': laterdate, 'source': source, 'location': location})
    records = cursor.fetchall()
```

Where I am stuck is how to handle multiple values for a single query string parameter.  In all instances I would want to use an `OR` operator for multiple values.

So in the above example I want to find records that match `location = loc1` or `location = loc2` or `location = loc3`.

Comment: Instead of `OR` look at `IN/ANY`. I'm guessing you are using `psycopg2` so take a look at [List adaptions(ANY)](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks you sir. You are a mighty and powerful wizard.